# Is FlurryAgent.getPhoneId() unique for each customer?

Tags: android, analytics, flurry

I was tracking the user behavior using flurry in my android app.
I came across a function called FlurryAgent.getphoneId()

**I had 2 questions:**

1) Is this Id unique to every single phone? I am trying to make this the unique Id for each customer. 
I have checked this id with 2 different devices and FlurryAgent.getphoneId() gives 2 different Ids. However, I am confused if those 2 ids are device Ids or unique user ids.
(I am afraid 2 Motorola Fire XT 530 may have the same FlurryAgent.getphoneId().)

2) After I clear app data this phoneId doesn't seem to be changed.
Where is this phoneId stored?

I have checked their website but no documentation on getphoneId is available. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flurry uses SHA1 Mac for iOS and Android ID for Android apps as device identifiers. These are used solely for internal identification purpose, and are not disclosed to developers. You need to use setUserID method to assign a unique user ID for a user in your app. Please be sure not to use this method to pass any private or confidential information about the user.

(Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)

Comment: Ya, I got a mail from support team explaining this. Thanks!